# JavaScript resize - div doesnt render properly - holy grail layout - css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, window-resize

I've just completed my "awesome" dynamic holy grail layout in css and jquery  https://jsfiddle.net/4hy2tkqv/

However, although the page renders as expected when I press F5 - it doesn't render the inner circle div inside my circle container properly when the browser window changes.

If I look at the variables in my firefox debugger,

```
$('.circle').height($('.circle_container').width());
$('.circle').width($('.circle_container').width());
```

the circle container width is zero!! - making the inner circle disappear when resizing. What I fail to understand is why when I press F5 everything seems to work just fine.

Comment: I am looking into it. in the meantime, notice that you have a small error here: $('col-empty').hide();  should be $('.col-empty').hide(); Also, consider using more css and less java-script (if any) for layout

Comment: you are setting circle_container width to a negative number, the result of this calculation:  $('.middle').width() - ($('.right').height() *2).

Comment: thank you for your time and input. I am quite new to this so any tips are very much appreciated; just glad that I finally arrived at that stage :)

Comment: Glad to help. Please provide a description of how this layout is supposed to behave. This way we know the expected result and can help you learn a clean, effective approach to achieving that result.

Comment: the idea is that if document.width() > document.hegiht()   two .col-empty are present that push the navigation and the circle in the middle of the screen. in case the document heigth is greater than the width, these two columns are to disapear pushing the navigation at the left and right of the browser window to make space for the circle in the middle

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to allocate a greater percentage of space to the middle column if the aspect ratio of the page is portrait versus landscape. Can you provide example dimensions for landscape and portrait? example: if screen width = 1920 & screen height =1080, left col w = x, middle width = y, right w = z.  If width and height of screen are reversed, what would x,y,and z be?

Comment: that is correct. there is no example height / width it is suppose to be dynamic - one size fits all - so any possible combination of x and y should give a decent result

Comment: just realising that pseudo selector such as circle::hover doesnt work ... is there reason to this madness?

Comment: just to clear it up for anyone that comes after use :hover not ::hover ....another one of these pointless pitfalls. I wish this was C++

Answer (score 0):

You got the Math wrong:

```
$('.circle_container').width($('.middle').width() - ($('.right').height() *2));
```

Should really be:

```
$('.circle_container').width($('.middle').width() - ($('.right').width() *2));
```

I.E. in your `else` clause.